# ! You can't use `macro parameter character #' in math mode error, but I need the #

Tags: math-mode, fonts, errors

**Goal:** Display several sources which have been used for research with spaces in between the words and non cursive letters

**Issue:** #-error and no space in between words and sources are written in cursive

**My latex skill level:** amateur

**Sample code:**

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 
    pointlessnumbers, 
    %draft,
    parskip=half,
    automark
        ]{scrartcl}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt} 

\usepackage[a4paper, left=2.2cm, right=2.2cm, top=2.5cm, bottom=2.5cm,]{geometry}%müsste das Design sein
\usepackage{scrpage2}
\clearscrheadfoot
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
 %foreignlanguage{sprache}{Text auf der Sprache} nur den Teil in {}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx,color}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,amsthm, amsfonts} 
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage[decimalsymbol=comma]{siunitx}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabulary} %hier könnte ein hämischer Komentar stehen;)
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor} 
\usepackage[centerlast,small,sc]{caption} %erlaubt Beschriftungen von Grafikfeldern und Tabellen, ...
\usepackage{here} 
\usepackage{siunitx}

\usepackage{titling}

\usepackage{subfigure}

\usepackage{hyperref}

%Mathe- Makros
%   \renewcommand{\vec}[1]{\boldsymbol{#1}} % Bold vector notation
    \renewcommand{\i}{\mathrm{i}}
    \newcommand{\e}{\mathrm{e}}
    \newcommand{\diff}{\mathrm{d}}
    \newcommand{\figref}[1]{Abb. \ref{#1}} %damit es nicht nur eqref gibt

    \newcommand{\ImNew}{\operatorname{Im}}
    \newcommand{\ReNew}{\operatorname{Re}}
    
    \newcommand{\xdot}{\! \, \cdot \! \,}
    \newcommand{\funof}[1]{{\color{gray}(#1)}} % makes function arguments nicer

%Titelseite
\title{lab}
\author{person}
\date{lab date: 10/09/2020}

%Dokument
\begin{document}
\setcounter{page}{0}
\maketitle
\thispagestyle{empty} % Keine Seitenzahl auf Titelseite
\ofoot{\upshape\thepage}

\clearpage
%Inhaltsverzeichnis
%\thispagestyle{empty}
\tableofcontents

\clearpage
%Hauptdokument
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\ihead{\upshape\scriptsize \leftmark}
\ohead{\upshape\scriptsize \thetitle}
%\ifoot{\upshape \scriptsize}
\ofoot{\upshape\thepage}

\subsection{Sources}
figure\\
%$\ref{fig:4}$%
$:[Wik21] Wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Refracting_telescope#Galilean_telescope, 2021 [Online; accessed 09/21/2021]$

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `#` has a special meaning in LaTeX (since it's used in macro definitions to stand for the arguments as `#1`, `#2`, etc.) therefore it can't be used directly as a character. If you want a literal `#`, you have to add a backslash (`\#`):

```latex
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\begin{document}
$a = \# + 2$
\end{document}
```

Independently of that, surrounding your sources with `$` indicates that they are mathematical expressions and therefore chages their spacing and uses an italic font. Just remove the `$`s to move them back into text mode.